# How to make Packard Bell ZE6 wake up when lid opens?

Tags: sleep, wake-up, lid

I use the Packard bell ZE6 laptop with win 7.

I want the computer to wake up from sleep mode when ever i open the lid, so i won't have to press any key after opening the lid to make it wake up. is it possible some how?

Comment: Older laptops don't always have lid-closed sensors.  I'm not certain that the ZE6 from Packard Bell has one... I haven't seen that brand name in almost a decade, but I live in America.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage If you live in America then your Packard Bells are called Gateway. ;)

Comment: It does sense when it is closed because then it goes to sleep. it also sense when it is opens because it turn's on some little light